# Power Query: Add multiple custom columns with List.Accumulate

Tags: excel, powerquery

In Excel Power Query, I try to add multiple custom columns with `List.Accumulate`and want to fill each column with values from the `current`value.

Here is my example code:

```
let
    Query1 = let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(),
    #"Expanded Content" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "Content", {"Region", "Industry", "Product type", "Series", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005"}, {"Region", "Industry", "Product type", "Series", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005"})
in
    #"Expanded Content",
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Query1,{{"2000", type number}, {"2001", type number}, {"2002", type number}, {"2003", type number}, {"2004", type number}, {"2005", type number}}),
    #"Added Custom" = List.Accumulate({2000..2005}, #"Changed Type", (state, current) => Table.AddColumn(state, "P_" & Number.ToText(current), each [current]))
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

Everything works fine and I get 6 new columns with the names P_2000, P_2001, etc.
As an example I wanted to fill each new column with the respective data from the "old columns". So in column "P_2000" I would like to have the same numbers as in the existing column "2000".

The error comes up with `each [current]` because it does not recognize the column name. Is there any workaround? I tried to convert the "current" value into text, but this did also not work for me.

Happy for any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but I think you'll want to change this line:

```
#"Added Custom" = List.Accumulate({2000..2005}, #"Changed Type", (state, current) => Table.AddColumn(state, "P_" & Number.ToText(current), each [current]))
```

to:

```
#"Added Custom" = List.Accumulate({2000..2005}, #"Changed Type", (state, current) => Table.AddColumn(state, "P_" & Number.ToText(current), each Record.Field(_, current)))
```

When handling records and accessing a field, I believe whatever you put between `[` and `]` is treated literally. Briefly and informally, the difference is:

- `[current]` = get the field that is literally named "current"
- `Record.Field(_, [current])` = get the field that is named whatever `current`'s value is

---

Unrelated, but since the columns you're adding are identical to the columns being copied, it might make more sense to use `Table.DuplicateColumn` ([details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-duplicatecolumn)) instead of `Table.AddColumn` ([details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-addcolumn)) inside your `List.Accumulate` code.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much - Record.Field is the answer to my question.
The only thing I had to change is "current" gives me a number value which I had to convert to a Text. The code in the end looks like that:
#"Added Custom" = List.Accumulate({2000..2005}, #"Changed Type", (state, current) => Table.AddColumn(state, "P_" & Number.ToText(current), each Record.Field(_, Number.ToText(current))))